# How to give a variable from another class a value from main method?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and so, I want easy and understandable answer.
You will know what I mean when you see the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Playeri user = new Playeri();
        Enemyu enem = new Enemyu();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        user.name = input.nextLine();
        user.showName();
        enem.showUserName();
    }
}

class Playeri {

    String name;

    void showName() {
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ".");
    }
}

class Enemyu {

    Playeri enemUser = new Playeri();

    void showUserName() {
        System.out.println("Hey, bro! Are you " + enemUser.name + "?");
    }
}
```

Suppose input is: John.

Then, output will be:

```
Your name is John.
Hey, bro! Are you null?
```

Here, I want John instead of null in output(line 2).
But I can't.

How can I access the same input to other classes (for e.g: Enemyu) other then the class having the declararion of the variable in which input is set (for e.g: Playeri)?

In Other Words:
How can multiple classes access the same value of variable that is set in a class through main method?

**Please answer my question!**

**Thank you very much!**

EDIT: Sorry for incorrect indentation in the code.

Comment: Use a setter in your `Enemy` class to set the reference to the `Player` instead of initializing a new `Player`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting value to the object's name variable.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

    Playeri user = new Playeri();

    Enemyu enem = new Enemyu();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    user.name = input.nextLine();

    user.showName();

    enem.showUserName();

    }

    }

    class Playeri {

        String name;

        void showName() {

        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ".");
        Enemyu.enemUser.name=name; // Set it like this
        }

        }

        class Enemyu {

        static Playeri enemUser = new Playeri(); // make it static

        void showUserName() {

        System.out.println("Hey, bro! Are you " + enemUser.name + "?");

        }

        }
```

Output -

```
John
Your name is John.
Hey, bro! Are you John?
```

This solves your problem, but It is recommended you use setter-getter method.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: Instead of string, if int is used which is changed further while processing the code, will the value of variable of type int be changed? Will static do not change its property to change? For e.g: <variable> = <variable> - 1;

Comment: Sorry... I accidentally give this answer -1 :(

Comment: For `static` variable, whether it is int or string, it is always possible to change it from anywhere using its classname. For `final` variable it is not possible once assigned value to it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be pleasure for me to give you +1!

Comment: Edit your answer so that I can give you +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a parameter to that method.

```
void showName(String myName) {

    System.out.println("Your name is " + myName + ".");

    }
```

and

```
enem.showUserName(user.name);
```

or, you could set it the way you did with the user class.

or, you could use mutators (setters/getters) in this case, a set-method, or pass it as a parameter to the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of your code.  The problem that you had was that you created two separate instances of Playeri and only set the name on one of the instances.  This solution only creates a single instance of Playeri, thus bypassing the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Playeri user = new Playeri();

        Enemyu enem = new Enemyu(user);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        user.name = input.nextLine();

        user.showName();

        enem.showUserName();

    }

}

class Playeri {

    String name;

    void showName() {

        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ".");

    }

}

class Enemyu {

    Playeri enemUser;

    public Enemyu( Playeri p ) {
        this.enemUser = p;
    }

    void showUserName() {

        System.out.println("Hey, bro! Are you " + enemUser.name + "?");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Enemyu` class create `getters` and `setters` for your field variables.

**Inside Enemeyu...**

```
private String name;

...

public void setName(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

...
```

**Then inside your main method...**

```
...

Enemyu enem = new Enemyu();
enem.setName("John");
```

Granted you might also want to provide your class with an overidden `toString()` method (which in your case is your `showName`). However, in your case; I don't think that will be necessary.

Your problem was that you were never setting the `name` field in the object.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: Instead of string, if int is used which is changed further while processing the code, will the value of variable of type int be changed? Will static do not change its property to change? For e.g: <variable> = <variable> - 1

Comment: You would want to create a field of `integer` value in your constructor and call the `getters/setters` to... well, set and get the values you need! :D @user3820248